# Is there a way to know at runtime if a driver is a kernel module or if it was statically linked?

Tags: kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

I need to create a test that would check if the driver for a specific device was a kernel module(as opposed to statically linked). Is there a way to know this information at run time? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: With what OS and kernel?

Comment: Its a proprietary OS with a linux kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lsmod` will list the currently loaded kernel modules. So, if a driver is not listed there then it was either built-in to the kernel or it isn't loaded. Most distributions should have a config file stored in their `/boot` directory, which contains the kernel configuration options that were used. If you were to download and unpack the source code for the same kernel version; copy the config file to `.config` at the top of the source tree; and then run `make menuconfig`, then you would be able to browse the configuration settings and see how that driver was configured.

In some cases, the kernel configuration is actually built in to the kernel itself, but I would have to look up how to access that :)

**Edit:**

Another, possibly quicker, option (if it's a pci device) is to run `lspci -v`. The output of that will tell you the name of the driver that is currently in use. If that isn't listed in lsmod, then you know it must be built-in.